MDX Returning Null Values Even With Non Empty
Good afternoon. Have an MDX query still returning null values even though I have non empty in the MDX. This query does run and it does return values where I would expect to see them. Trying to get rid of all the null lines. Looking for assistance. Thanks.
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[Total Open PO and Planned] as 
        ([Measures].[Quantity Open - P]) + ([Measures].[Planned Order Quantity])

    MEMBER [Measures].[Open Purchase Orders] as
        ([Measures].[Quantity Open - P])

    MEMBER [Measures].[Forecasted Orders] as 
        ([Measures].[Forecast Quantity])

    MEMBER [Measures].[Planned Orders] as
        [Measures].[Planned Order Quantity]

SELECT 
NON EMPTY
    ({
        [Measures].[Total Open PO and Planned],
        [Measures].[Open Purchase Orders],
        [Measures].[Forecasted Orders],
        [Measures].[Planned Orders]
    }) 
    ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY
    {
        [Item Branch].[Business Unit Code].CHILDREN
        *
        [Items].[Item Number 02].CHILDREN
    }
    ON ROWS 

FROM
(SELECT 
    (
        {[Items].[P1 Flag].&[]}

) ON COLUMNS FROM
[Buyer]

)

enter image description here
I was expecting the Non Empty to remove null records. Thanks

Non empty doesn't filter out calculated measures. Because your measures are defined in the query they're never filtered by the Non empty clause. Try a Filter function instead.

I tried adding a filter function on just the first measure. System through an out of memory error after running a few minutes. Any thought on how to handle?
